# How can we use OWL Ontologies to link AVRO schemas from different microservices?

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, rdf, avro, owl

We use Apache Kafka and microservices publishing and subscribing to the data exposed by other microservices.

Currently the data is a bit heterogenous and a lot of guesswork happens in terms of "is there any microservice publishing the data i need?", "where to find a data source for customer like entities?", "what data does team x publish?".

It seems to me that the problem starts perhaps with proper modelling. Since AVRO is already a schema (for JSON documents), I would like to explore ways to go into the semantic layer of relating various concepts exposed by these microservices so that later on people and microservices can query this set of relations and find data sources that they would not normally be aware of, thus increasing productivity.

Do you know of any project that integrated Kafka or AVRO with OWL Ontologies? 
Or more generally in the land of microservices do you know of pragmatic and nice application of ontologies to help offer visibility on data and various parties can search for "customer like entities" for instance, across the organisation?

Related questions on Quora:

- [How can AVRO schemas used in Kafka topics be reused to generate OWL ontologies and how can OWL ontologies be used to generate AVRO schemas? What are other ways to inter-op?](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-can-AVRO-schemas-used-in-Kafka-topics-be-reused-to-generate-OWL-ontologies-and-how-can-OWL-ontologies-be-used-to-generate-AVRO-schemas-What-are-other-ways-to-inter-op)
- [How would you mix OWL ontologies with AVRO schemas needed in Apache Kafka, to describe the same domain without much duplication?](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-would-you-mix-OWL-ontologies-with-AVRO-schemas-needed-in-Apache-Kafka-to-describe-the-same-domain-without-much-duplication)
- [What are the ways to define a domain model that can be freely shared across organisations and be laterally developed in a decentralised fashion, allow for different ways of modelling the Customer? Is OWL ontologies a way?](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-are-the-ways-to-define-a-domain-model-that-can-be-freely-shared-across-organisations-and-be-laterally-developed-in-a-decentralised-fashion-allow-for-different-ways-of-modelling-the-Customer-Is-OWL-ontologies-a)
- [What kind of metadata would you use to associate data sources like Kafka topics or db tables that they represent Entity X and they are owned by team Y? Would OWL Ontologies be ok to model entities across microservices and their similarities?](https://www.quora.com/What-kind-of-metadata-would-you-use-to-associate-data-sources-like-Kafka-topics-or-db-tables-that-they-represent-Entity-X-and-they-are-owned-by-team-Y-Would-OWL-Ontologies-be-ok-to-model-entities-across])